# Выбор сервера

Tags: веб-сервер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, это хороший сервер? Заказываю у selectel.ru

[image]

Comment: @ХэшКод, если бы там была активность, я бы задал. А так там надо ответа 100 лет ждать и то, не факт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это 4096 руб. в месяц да + еще и VDS - фигня, SWAP раздела не будет, т.е. оперативки всего 4Гб.

За 4096 руб. лучше взять облако, и по ресурсам лучше и по потреблению лучше.

А вообще на твоем месте если можешь потратить 4К на VDS возьми в том же селектеле выделенный сервер

Intel Core2Quad Q8300 2.5 ГГц (4 ядра) Акция: скидки 15% и 30%
6 Гб DDR3    2 x 500 Гб SATA 3500 руб.

Счастья будет намного больше. + SWAP раздел будешь иметь. и стоит дешевле!

и по твоему вопросу

```
Подскажите пожалуйста, это хороший сервер?
```

Нет плохой возьми выделенный, как я и описал выше!

Comment: @Shrek, а операционная система Ubuntu нужна 32 бита или 64? и разбивка жёсткого диска как, что выбрать? swap - 12 Gb, / - other, swap - 12 Gb, / - 10 Gb, /home - other или / - всё?

Comment: Я бы взял 64, swap-12 остальное как желаешь нужным, можно оставить как есть и как предлагает сам селектел. ибо /var/www/ можно потом настроить ссылками к каждому пользователю.

Comment: Ах. да и взял бы я дебиан а не убунту, но это у каждого свои предпочтения.

ну и RAID 1 сделать

Comment: @Shrek, а чем дебиан лучше убунты?)

Comment: Debian хорош на серверах, Ubuntu лучше подходит для десктопов.

В Debian софт устаревший, но стабильный, в Ubuntu – самый современный, но возможны глюки.

Debian может быть установлен в минимальной комплектации и в дальнейшем наращиваться по потребностям; Ubuntu устанавливает массу «юзерофильной хрени»

Debian – полностью свободный дистрибутив, разрабатываемый сообществом, тогда как разработка Ubuntu контролируется коммерческой фирмой