# Выбор сервера на 5000 человек

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Добрый день. На моем сайте будет примерно 5000 чел. онлайн, каждый из которых работает с mysql, примерно с 5 - 7 базами  (сообщения, друзья и т.п),

- Хар-ки сервера: VPS
- CPU: 800 Мгц
- RAM: 384 Мб
- HDD: 8192 Мб

Подскажите сколько человек вытянет мой сервер и пожалуйста подскажите хороший сервер под 5000 онлайна с панелью управления, желательно с ISP MANAGER/

Comment: - Для таких вещей (мне, кстати, безумно интересно, как можно, не имея проекта, уже знать его онлайн) придуманы [`Scale Server'a.`](http://www.clodo.ru/scale-server/review/)

- Создаете проект, выбираете для него минимальные параметры и делаете небольшой задел вверх для того, чтобы в случае, если ваш сервак начинает настигать `slashdot` эффект, на него можно было достучаться и натюнить параметры -- и вперед.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать понимаешь у нас тут мега разработчики теперь, это раньше парились сначала писали код, потом его оптимизировали, потом БД подключали потом с хостингов переходили на сервера, а теперь разрабы стали умнее, экстрасенсорнее и т.д.

Comment: @Shrek Угу `:)` Пойду, пожалуй, за полчасика проект на 47 миллионов онлайна запущу -- надо быть в тренде.

Comment: Возьми в команду, я оптимизирую, и сразу будем думать об онлайне на 65 миллионов.

Comment: ну а чего кота за одно место тянуть? =)

Comment: ахха)) Проект готов, просто у меня интеграция с другими сервисами идёт, а от туда не плохой траф, поэтому и задумался...

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал dedicteded + erlang,  но мне кажется, что это не подходит.  
Как вариант: разверните узел erlang на localhost, по мере необходимости на dedictaded, а потом уже на 10+ серверах.

Answer (score 2):

> На моем сайте будет примерно 5000 чел.

так примерно или будет?

384 метра не выдержит точно столько в онлайне.

Какова сумма для трат на сервер есть?

[Вот тема про сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189092/) все уже давно написано всем просто лень воспользоваться поиском.

ps ты явно не понимаешь что такое БД и таблицы

> примерно с 5 - 7 базами  (сообщения,
>   друзья и т.п),

Comment: спасибо, я перепутал название просто:)

Comment: 2000 руб в бюджете

Comment: 2К это немного конечно, но опять же можно взять выделенный сервер

Intel Atom D525 1.8 ГГц (2 ядра)
2 Гб DDR2
500 Гб SATA

стоимость 1,5К/мес.

ps люди хватит смотреть в сторону VPS - это виртуалка, урезанный сервер во всех понятиях!

Comment: Нашёл тариф:Оператива:2400 MB;Процессор:2800 Mhz;Место:16 GB;Трафик
сумма входящего и исходящего:1500 GB, хостер:fastvps;Цена:806.0 руб. Он вытянет 5к онлайна?

Comment: @Shrek, атом не осилит такой нагрузки)

Comment: Атом хоть будет работать лучше чем то что предлагает ТС.
за 2К ничего не осилит такой нагрузки в России :)

У нас очень дорогие сервера, все наживаются на всех - это такая политика партии.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что 5000 клиентов онлайн будет не одновременно.